# Store division of numbers in decimal result 0

Tags: c#

After division when storing result in float,double,decimal it gives result as 0. How can i store it.

```
decimal days = 0.00m;
days= 110 / 480;
```

Actual result is 0.2291666666666667 but i'm getting 0 in variable days. i have tries data types float,double & decimal.

Comment: try days= 110.0 / 480;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you correct result :

```
decimal days = 0.00m;
days= 110m / 480m;
```

Explanation : To represent a decimal value 'm' is suffixed

```
 110 is Int32
 110m is Decimal
```

As you have defined days as decimal, values used in the calculation should also be decimal. Hope this helps to understand the value representation.

As @dumetrulo pointed out : 110 & 480 both are integers, 110 / 480 after integer division gives result 0; this result is then implicitly cast to decimal and stays 0.

Comment: To clarify: ``110 / 480`` is an integer division with result 0; this result is then implicitly cast to decimal, and stays 0.

Comment: you are right there, I'm adding it to the solution